# using Ruby to check that username exists in sqlite3 database

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I am new to ruby. I am trying use ruby accept username from user and check it against sqlite3 database to see if it exists. if it exists, then ask user to input a different username. I have tried below code but it doesn't work. Please help me. 
The sqlite3 table is "cpu_dues" and the column I am checking against is "user_name". Then I am accepting a variable "user" to compare with values in the database.

```
require 'sqlite3'
print "Enter your Username: "
user = gets.chomp().to_s
db = SQLite3::Database.open 'ipu_db.db'
db.results_as_hash = false
user_exist = [db.execute( "SELECT user_name FROM ipu_dues        WHERE user_name = ('#{user}')"), 1]

if user_exist[0] = user
puts "Keep asking for username"
else
puts "accept username and carry on"
end
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on _"doesn't work"_. What does not work? Is there an unexpected result? What do you expect, what happens instead? Is there an error, what is the exacty error message?

Comment: Don't forget to **use placeholder values** to avoid [SQL injection bugs](https://bobby-tables.com). This is easy to do: `db.execute( "SELECT user_name FROM ipu_dues        WHERE user_name=?', [ user ])`

Comment: Tip: If you're just testing for existence: `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead, that doesn't fetch data which means it runs way faster.

Comment: Another big problem: `if user_exist[0] = user` will *assign*. If you want to test use `==`.

Comment: Ruby also omits empty args, like `gets.chomp` is fine. The `to_s` is extraneous.

Comment: @tadman, thanks for your tips. I used SELECT COUNT(*) to return a single index array and convert this array into integer. then compare with this integer to determine if the username exists. thanks for your tips. much appreciated.

Comment: this code now works for me. user_exist = db.execute( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ipu_dues WHERE user_name = ('#{user}')")
comp = user_exist.join.to_i thanks to @tadman

Comment: You still *really* need to get rid of that SQL injection bug.